# fine uploader doesn't have disallowedExtensions

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

`fine uploader` has `allowedExtensions` validation, but doesn't have `disallowedExtensions`. I want to disallow specific 2 or 3 extensions.

I can do it by php, but I want to prevent it before loading files.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily enforce *any* restrictions you want in Fine Uploader using the `onValidate`, `onValidateBatch`, and/or `onSubmit` callbacks.

For example, to exclude any files with a .txt extension:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function(id, name) {
            return qq.getExtension(name) !== "txt";
        }
    }
});
```

There is also an outstanding pull request to add a disallowedExtensions property to the `validation` option, but this is not currently a high priority, as it's quite easy to enforce extensions this way via callbacks.